# How to format a virtual hard-drive created with VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

How can one totally format a virtual hard-drive created with VirtualBox?

I don't want to tottaly delete the drive and open another --- I just consider to format the existing one... How can this be done?

It's a VDI virtual drive btw, but in ask the question in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just entered a virtual Ubuntu desktop CD to the Virtual machine, restarted the system and then reinstalled the OS regularly... It actually even saved me time cause I didn't need the extra wait of creating a new drive.

Answer (score 5):

You would need to boot into a system that can then run the Format command; for example boot from CD.

However, as it takes you 10 seconds to make a *'new one'*, it is really not worth any effort to format the old one. In the Settings for the VM, drop the existing one, go to Storage/Add Hard Disk, give it a size, and you are done.

Formatting a virtual hard disk is like deleting all existing characters in a text file to be able reuse the file - it's easier to just make a new file, they are free and instantaneous.